# Prove that $\left\{ 1 + i l ~ | ~ i \in 0, ..., p - 1; i \neq \frac{p - 1}{l} \right\}$ is a multiplicative subgroup of $\mathbb Z / (pl) \mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, coding-theory

I have a prime number $p$ and another number that divides $p - 1$, let's call it $l ~ | ~ (p - 1)$. Define their product as $q = l \cdot p$.

Moreover, I have a set $S = \left\{ 1 + i l ~ | ~ i \in 0, ..., p - 1; i \neq \frac{p - 1}{l} \right\}$.
I want to show that $(S, \cdot)$ is a multiplicative, cyclic subgroup of the multiplicative group of integers modulo $q$, $(\mathbb Z / q \mathbb Z)^\times$.

---

**Example**: Choose $p = 19$, $l = 9$, so $q = 19 \cdot 9 = 171$, then $S = \{1, 10, 28, 37, 46, 55, 64, 73, 82, 91, 100, 109, 118, 127, 136, 145, 154, 163\}$ with multiplication modulo $q$ is a cyclic multiplicative subgroup of $(\mathbb Z / q \mathbb Z)^\times$ with generators $g \in \{ 10, 91, 109, 127, 136, 154 \}$.

Any hints are greatly appreciated! Showing that $S$ is a sub*set* is fairly straightforward, but I'm struggling to show that it is closed under multiplication and cyclic.

Comment: It should be straightforward (by multiplication) to show that $(1+il)(1+jl)=1+kl$ for some $k$

Comment: Are you sure about $i\ne \frac{p-1}{2}$ in the definition of $S$?  Shouldn't it be $i\ne \frac{p-1}{l}$?  Your example seems to omit the term $1+il$ with $i=\frac{p-1}{l}$, rather than $i=\frac{p-1}{2}$.

Comment: With $S$ properly defined, I think this solves the problem.  Let $\gamma$ be any generator of the group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$.  Using the Chinese remainder thm, there exists a unique $g\in\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ such that $g\equiv 1\pmod{l}$ and $g\equiv \gamma\pmod{p}$.  Then $S$ is a cyclic subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^\times$ generated by $g$.

Comment: Thank you very much, @WETutorialSchool! Of course you're right about it being $i \neq \frac{p - 1}{l}$, I fixed that typo.

Comment: What you're saying is probably correct, but I'm maybe a bit slow to understand the answer you gave that uses the Chinese Remainder Theorem. So the theorem says that a solution for $g$ exists, but what is it finally that makes $g$ generate the subgroup $(S, \cdot)$?

Comment: I think I might get it now. For $g$ to generate $S$, all of its elements $1 + i l$ must be representable as $1 + il \equiv g^k \pmod q$ for some $k$. So it has to be both $1 + il \equiv g^k \pmod l$ and $1 + il \equiv g^k \pmod p$, which are obviously true because $1 \equiv 1^k \pmod l$ and $1 + il \equiv \gamma^k \pmod p$  have solutions.